# How to delete/kill multiple copies of the same activity in android?

Tags: android

I have an activity which performs the basic login operation and authentication. I am able to move to another activity when the login is successful. I am loading the same activity if the login fails or if inappropriate values have been entered by the user.

The problem I am facing is

When login fails, I display the same activity. If that is done multiple times, the same activity is displayed. When I press back, multiple copies of the same activity show up before I can completely exit.
How can I delete/kill the previous activities that are piling up behind?

Below is my code in MainActivity.java

```html
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

if(!email.getText().toString().isEmpty() && (!password.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
{
  isValid = login_validation(email.getText().toString());
  if (isValid) {
      SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                                            "MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
      editor.putString("email", email.getText().toString());
      editor.putString("password", password.getText().toString());
      editor.commit();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second_Activity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
     }
  else
  {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed. Please enter correct                                                         credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
  }
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email / Password cannot be empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
      MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
}


}
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best way to do this would be to use an AsyncTask. The methods of Async task are very well suited for this operation. What I understand of a login operation is that you somewhere would be connecting to a server and this should be done off the main thread - hence one more valid point to use an Async Task.

Comment: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
Or call finish() before starting new activity

Or just clear the UI fields

Comment: finish() works fine.. But what if I have 5 screens.. Say A-B-C-D-E
Now I am at E if my all work is done then I move to activity B using the below code

startActivity(intent);
this.finish();

this code will be kill only E activity but I want to kill C,D activities too... How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont open same activity using below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You are already on this screen so just remove above lines

Comment: Then how to load the same activity again.. Does MainActivity reloads again?

Comment: Could you tell me why you want to reload?

Comment: Oh yeah I got it.. My bad.. I can just reset the fields in the layout. I think that would work